# FOR XML PATH makes stored procedure slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using FOR XML PATH in my stored procedure to concatenate rows.But it gives me performance issue.can any one please tell me a function that i can use instead of for xml path.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `CLR Aggregate function` to do concatenation.
Example here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2022/concat-aggregates-sql-server-clr-function/

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate storing the string in a variable, just with a simple select.
Example concatenating with a comma:

```
DECLARE @MyConcatenateData VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @MyConcatenateData = COALESCE(@MyConcatenateData + ',', '') + MyTextColumn
FROM MyTable
```